# Flask/Python 3 internal server error 500 when posting from html form

Tags: python, html, forms, python-3.x, flask

I'm new to Python & Flask and trying to set up a very basic script that takes information submitted from a form and posts it to a new page (I know, very simple right?)

I'm having limited success and can't figure out what the problem is here. It's working when I have 2 out of the 4 form fields selected in the python file:

```
name=request.form['name']
age=request.form['age']
```

This works fine and does what I expect it to do - Renders the output.html page containing 'name' & 'age'

but as soon as I try to add any more, I'm getting an internal server error (500), even through I'm copying & pasting the exact same code and only changing the variables (i.e 'number' & 'feeling') - In both the .py file and the input & output html files.

Heres the code..

Python code:

(The input form is on the /input/ page. "input_1" renders the output.html file)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
from dbconnect import connection
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'kuywergiukrewgkbyuwe'
toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)

app.config.update(TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD = True)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template ("main.html")

@app.route('/input/')
def input():
    return render_template ("input.html")

@app.route('/input/', methods=["POST"])
def input_1():
    name=request.form['name']
    age=request.form['age']
    number=request.form['number']
    feeling=request.form['feeling']

    return render_template('output.html', name = name, age = age, number = number, feeling = feeling)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The input.html file:

(Contains the input form)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>devserver</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for("static", filename="css/bootstrap.css") }}">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for("static", filename="favicon.ico") }}">
    </head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col">

        <h2>Input form</h2>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('input') }}">

            <label for="InputForm">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"/>

            <label for="InputForm">Age</label>
            <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control"/>

            <label for="InputForm">Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="number" class="form-control"/>

            <label for="InputForm">Feeling</label>
            <input type="text" name="feeling" class="form-control"/>

            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The output.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>devserver</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for("static", filename="css/bootstrap.css") }}">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for("static", filename="favicon.ico") }}">
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col">

        <h2>Output form</h2>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <form>

            <h3>Output 1</h3>
            <P>Your name is = {{name}}</p>

            <h3>Output 2</h3>
            <P>Your age is = {{age}} </p>

            <h3>Output 3</h3>
            <P>Your number is = {{number}}</p>

            <h3>Output 4</h3>
            <P>Your feeling is = {{feeling}} </p>


            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I cant understand why it works with only 2. When I comment out the following it works fine:

```
@app.route('/input/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def input():
    name=request.form['name']
    age=request.form['age']
    #number=request.form['number']
    #feeling=request.form['feeling']

    return render_template('output.html', name = name, age = age) #number = number, feeling = feeling)
```

It's probably something quite obvious but I just can't see it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried turning on debugging, exceptions, looking at the output of your flask server, etc?

Comment: If you reduce this to a [MCVE] (something you should do generally when posting to SO), it works just fine. So your problem is something else. This https://gist.github.com/pvg/331760af664b34bda5a895d073334e81 works just fine with your templates.

Answer (score 0):

You usually use `url_for` when you have to generate urls. I would rather not complicate matter when I have to pass multiple parameters.What I would do is just this :

```
<form method="post" action="/input">
```

and in the app file :

```
@app.route('/input', methods=["POST"])
def input_1():
    name=request.form['name']
    age=request.form['age']
    number=request.form['number']
    feeling=request.form['feeling']

    return render_template('output.html', name = name, age = age, number = number, feeling = feeling)
```

But if you really wanna generate urls then put the function you want to generate url for and also pass the arguments .

```
<form method="post" action={{url_for('input_1',name=name)}}>
```

and then call funtion `input_1` like this:

```
@app.route('/input/<name>') #you can add parameters as per your wish
def input_1(name):
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Downvoting should be supported by an explanation if its not malicious .